# Senior staff member hinted at a promotion to a new position

Tags: promotion

I work in a support role in an expanding company.

While I was working, a more senior staff member I've never met before came to me and said there is likely to be a new role soon in a higher position, and told me about it and asked whether I could do it.

We wear different uniforms depending on our role and area in the company, so that's how I know he is more senior.

I have skills that I don't need for my position and I think the position he described would be more suitable, and I think there is no one else in my section who would be qualified to do that job.

He asked whether I planned to continue working at the company for a long time, and I said I do.

I told him I could do the job, and told him about my experience in similar roles.

He said "great" and walked away.

From a game theory perspective, I don't know whether he asked about whether I plan to stay at the company for a long time because he wants to find someone permanent for the new position, or whether he used the story of a new position to break the ice in preparation for finding out whether I plan to stay at the company for some other reason.

Each seems equally likely to me, but maybe 1 is more likely than the other.

My question is: what should I do now?

Assuming there will be a new position and that he just wanted to make sure I wanted to stay with the company for a long time before offering it to me, should I just forget about it? If the new position is created and I'm the most suitable person for it, he or someone else will ask me again.

If they find someone else for the position, I don't expect they would come and tell me that it has been filled, and I don't want to be waiting forever.

Or should I ask him again after a few days?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Please leave a comment why you downvoted so OP can edit.

Comment: I didn't downvote but telling about the region could help a little to evaluate this situation.

Answer (score 9):

> Each seems equally likely to me

Not if you consider energy spent.

1. Why would he talk to you for a long time if he only wanted to ask a simple question?
2. Why does a senior you've never met before suddenly take an interest in you?

You are probably considered for the position.

Talk to him in a week or so, but don't take anything for granted in the meantime. Continue your life as normal.

Comment: Nice answer.  Remember its not done until its completely **done**.

Answer (score 1):

Your description sounds like someone unknown to you came to you from an unknown department, told you some news and asked you a question before vanishing again in the mist of mystery.

I don't know which work-culture you are in but for this kind of matters, shouldn't there be manager, boss, other superior that you know and who would be responsible to talk to you about these things, instead of someone unknown?

> what should I do now?

Without meaning to sound funny, the first thing you should do is: wonder who this mysterious unknown person is, what they know about you and why they came to exactly **you**. Plus you should know if the news you were told is really true.
Find this out, find this person and show you are interested in what they said, or ask your boss about that. This depends on your company structure.

If you know more about this and you want to apply for this job, do what you need to do to apply for it. I hardly can imagine that waiting for things to come is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find out who this manager is and what role they play in the business.  You may have been recommended by your existing manager or possibly your good work has been noticed by others in the company.

In my experience it is entirely possible that this person wants to offer you an opportunity to shine.  This happened to me may years ago. An employee from the same company was getting a cross transfer to another department and approached me suggesting I apply for his outgoing job.  He said the applications for the position had closed but suggested calling his manager to see if they would accept a late application which fortunately for me they did. Anyhow to cut a long story short I got the job over 90 other applicants.  :)

Good work and demonstrating your ability can pay off.  Clearly your efforts haven't gone unnoticed. If it was me I'd apply for the job if you wanted it.